# Quicklisp: How do i unregister a local system from quicklisp

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

The scenario is that I have a (old) back level version of local-time which I have registered as a local project. Of course, this clashes with something else I want to do, so I want to unregister it as a local project (but not remove it) and use the quicklisp version. Any hints on how to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: _How_ did you "register" it?  Put in into your local-projects folder?  Do you have a `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf` for ASDF?

Comment: I do. but it does not help much. I have taken the brute force approach and moved the offending library elsewhere. I will figure out how to deal with multiple version later. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a short way to do that with Quicklisp right now. The easiest thing is to move it out of `~/quicklisp/local-projects/` or your ASDF source registry directories.

Quicklisp works by modifying `asdf:*system-definition-search-functions*`. It could be feasible to add another function to the front that loaded certain systems from Quicklisp regardless of ASDF or local-projects visibility. Nothing like that exists today, though.

Comment: Thanks Xach, I gathered that after reading parts of quicklisp.